# SnmpV3AdaptorServer snmpV1Trap throws IOException and not releasing its resource

Tags: java, snmp, jdmk

I am using SNMPAdaptorServer for sending trap.

```
snmpAdaptor.snmpV1Trap(...)
```

For some reason it throwing IOException:

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:625)
at com.sun.management.comm.SnmpAdaptorServer.sendTrapMessage(SnmpAdaptorServer.java:2266)
at com.sun.management.comm.SnmpAdaptorServer.sendTrapPdu(SnmpAdaptorServer.java:2237)
at com.sun.management.comm.SnmpAdaptorServer.snmpV1Trap(SnmpAdaptorServer.java:1791)
at com.sun.management.comm.SnmpAdaptorServer.snmpV1Trap(SnmpAdaptorServer.java:1704)
```

i think IP is not reachable in snmp peer so generating IOException.
but issue is that one thread named **CommunicatorServer** is running infinite time. Some IO resouce is not released by this.

i have called SNMPAdaptorServer.stop(). it should release all resource.

how to fix this? [image]

Comment: This  https://issues.jboss.org/browse/MODCLUSTER-327 helps to stop generating exception but thread is not stopped yet.

Comment: not duplicate.. its about jdmk framework and that post is about multisocket